# django formset not working properly after removing few forms

Tags: django, django-forms, formset

I'm using a django formset having 5 forms. After entering data and posting them to my. I validate the formset and save the valid forms(suppose 2 are saved) and remove them from formset and unvalidated forms(3 in this case) are rendered back on django template. Now, after correcting the data on these 3 forms, I post them again.

Now in my view, I'm getting 5 forms again
and 2 forms which were saved earlier are posted with empty data.. because of which my

```
formset.is_valid()
```

returns false and error is raised.

Can anybody tell me the reason why this is happening and how to fix it?
Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**: I have found out that issue is because form-TOTAL_FORMS and form-INITIAL_FORMS are still not same ater removing forms. Any quick help to update these numbers?

Comment: You probably shouldn't save ANY of the forms till all of them are valid.